# Complete orthonormal system in a finite dimension Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have to solve the following problem of functional analysis.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space of dimension $N$. Prove that every complete orthonormal system in $H$ has $N$ elements and that $H$ is linearly isometric to $\mathbb{R}^N$.

I know that any orthonormal system is linearly independent and that every Hilbert space $H$ has a complete orthonormal system. In my opinion, I must prove that the number of elements of the complete orthonormal system is less or equal to $N$ and that it cannot be greater than $N$, but I cannot start with this argument. Is this idea the right way to solve the problem? Please, help me! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{ e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n \}$ is a complete orthonormal system, then, for every $x \in H$,
$$
         \left(x - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k\right)\perp e_j,\;\;\; 1 \le j \le n.
$$
Because $\{ e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n \}$ is complete, then
$$
            x - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k =0.
$$
In other words, every complete orthonormal system is spanning. You can see that such a set of vectors is also linearly independent because
$$
         \sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k e_k =0 \implies \alpha_j = \left\langle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k e_k,e_j\right\rangle=0,\;\;\; 1 \le j \le n.
$$
Therefore any complete orthonormal system $\{ e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n\}$ is a basis.

For the last part, let $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_N\}$ be a complete orthonormal system for $H$. Define a map $U : \mathbb{R}^{N}\rightarrow H$ by
$$
        U(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_N) = \alpha_1 e_1 + \alpha_2 e_2+\cdots+\alpha_N e_N.
$$
This map is linear, and it is surjective because $\{e_1,\cdots,e_N\}$ is a basis of $H$. Furthermore, because of orthonormality,
$$
    \|U(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_N)\|_{H}=\|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_n e_n \|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_n^{2} = \|(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_N)\|_{R^{N}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Well the definition of dimension means that any linearly independent system can have at most N elements. Then using Gram-Schmidt we get that any orthogonal hence any orthonormal system can have at most N elements.

The isomorphism with $\mathbb{R^N}$ is just by identifying each element of the orthonormal set with one of the unit vectors in N-dimensional Euclidean space.